# Show image that is selected from UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

The app opens the pickerController and selects the image, but it doesn't show the image that was selected. I tried putting `self` before `image_sel.image = photo`, but it didn't work neither. When I put `print` inside extension it prints and it also hits breakpoints.

```
lazy var image_sel: UIImageView = {
    let i = UIImageView()
    i.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    i.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "noimage")

    return i
}()

@objc func imageSelect(){
    let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    pickerController.delegate = self

    present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

extension CameraPage: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let photo = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
            image_sel.image = photo
        }

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: try removing lazy and check

Comment: @SivajeeBattina still not working/

Comment: This may be minor but it may not be - try "force unwrapping" the image (that's what I do). Replace the `as? UIImage` with as! UIImage`. Either way, see if `photo` is nil in your code.

Comment: @dfd it must have an optional type

Comment: My code works fine and the only difference is the force unwrap.

Answer (score 0):

> lazy var image_sel: UIImageView

You are using a lazy var property, might be the case that you still don't have a object when you try to assign the value to ImageView.

Try to use the image on another UIImageView to see if that's the problem.

[Check your view stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j274A.png)

Comment: What's you value for `let photo = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage`

Comment: `<UIImage: 0x6080000bc680> size {3000, 2002} orientation 0 scale 1.000000`

Comment: Well, you could read it more here:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/148513/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-3-part-1

DispatchQueue.main.async { 
     Your code here    
}

Comment: No i have not tried doing that.Where shouold i add it?

Comment: func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let photo = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { image_sel.image = photo
 }         }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

Comment: Can you provide full class code? There must be something messing up with your code beside those methods you provided. Can you also try with DispatchQueue.main.sync instead of async?

Comment: let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

instead of 

 let pickedImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage

Comment: @sakoaskoaso , check your views stack, you might have a view in front of your UIImageView.

Comment: I added a image to my answer.

Comment: Do you see the image there after you add to UIImageView?

Comment: Yes i see `noimage` that i add by default

Comment: so comment everyplace you have image_sel.image = and just stay with the one of the delegate of PickerView. Check results again. 

My guess is somehow, you area adding as a subview with that picture already.

Comment: but i need it to be `noimage` by defualt

Comment: Sure, you may need it once your get things working, but right now @ppinho is giving you good advice - you need to **debug** the issue first, **then** add back in the finished code.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't saw where you display `image_sel`. Did you use `addSubview`?